# Error: The caller does not have permission for google chat bot in node

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, google-hangouts

I keep getting the error "The caller does not have permission" when trying to send a message to a google chat room. I've added the bot to the room, and I can list rooms (see the console.log), so I know that my credentials are loaded and valid. Additionally, the room I'm trying to send to is in the list of rooms returned in my console.log. Not sure what's the problem.

```
import { Auth, chat_v1 } from "googleapis";

const postMessage = async (message: string) => {
  const roomId = '<myroom>';

  let jwtClient = new Auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: './googlekeys.json',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot']
  });
  const chat = new chat_v1.Chat({ auth: jwtClient });
  const rooms = await chat.spaces.list();
  rooms.data.spaces?.map((s) => {
    console.log(s);
  });
  await chat.spaces.messages.create({
    parent: `spaces/${roomId}`,
    requestBody: {
      text: message,
    }
  });
}
```

My googlekeys.json file format:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "<project_id>",
  "private_key_id": "<private_key_id>",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\<key>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "<client_email>",
  "client_id": "<client_id>",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/starting-account-<account>"
}
```

Comment: A couple questions in order to investigate further: How your `googlekeys.json` looks like (sanitized version, without token)? When using **async/await** I strongly recommend you to use try-catch block.

Comment: @JoseVasquez I've updated the question to include my googlekey.json file. Agree with the try-catch, was try-catching this whole function but better to move it inside it.

Comment: Can you please confirm that your **[bot configuration](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/chat.googleapis.com/hangouts-chat) > Bot Status is not DISABLED?**

Comment: @JoseVasquez it's set to "Live - available to users"

Comment: This can be given by [this configuration](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/incoming-bot-node#403_the_caller_does_not_have_permission) In order to make sure that this is not the reason of your error, can you check if your **[admin console](https://admin.google.com/) > Apps > G Suite > Settings for Google Chat and classic Hangouts > Chat Bots** has **Allow users to install chat bots** option off?

Comment: The thing is I’ve already got it installed in a room, and can chat to it. I just can’t publish to the room asynchronously

Comment: Just to be clear, by "I just can't publish to the room" you mean you can't **create a message** through your bot?. I just wanted to confirm that for some reason the **Chat Bots** option was turned off after the bot was installed. Otherwise it has to do with your service account or your Chat API configuration. As I said, take a look into this [well-known error](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/incoming-bot-node#403_the_caller_does_not_have_permission) in case it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had a room that the bot could not post to. This room contained myself and one other person. The bot worked when I removed the other person from the room.

We were both members of the Google Group it@ourdomain.com. In the Permissions section on the Hangouts Chat API Configuration page(https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/chat.googleapis.com/hangouts-chat) I had set "Specific people and groups in your domain" to:

> me@ourdomain.com, it@ourdomain.com

I changed this to expand the group membership to the individual members:

> me@ourdomain.com,f@ourdomain.com,a@ourdomain.com,j@ourdomain.com

This fixed it. I guess groups are not expanded by Google in this setting even though it says you can enter groups.